# Style resource inheriting from parent

Tags: xaml

I've got two stack panels nested within another stackpanel, the nested stack panels both have images in which need to be the same size, so I've used a style resorce. But this means duplicating the style resources in each stack panel. As shown;

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horiztonal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Image />
        <Image />
        <Image />
        <Image />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horiztonal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Image />
        <Image />
        <Image />
        <Image />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Is there a way to set this style on my surrounding stackpanel and have the children inherit that style, or would I be looking at making a style template (as shown; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styling-and-templating) and applying it individually to my images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend inheriting style using "previous style" as the base. Instead, I would define the style explicitly as the base style as a static resource, and then apply the style to any control that needs that style (or inherit the style).
For ex:

In the User Control level, let's define the base style.

```
<UserControl>
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <!--Define StackPanel Style with a key as the base-->
      <Style x:Key="ImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
          <Setter .... />
      </Style>
      <!-- To apply the style above, you need to explicitly set the style using Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}"-->
   </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

In the body, we can apply the style to specific Control, but in our case we want to apply to all Images inside the OuterStackPanel, therefore:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="OuterStackPanel">
   <StackPanel.Resources>
      <!-- Without specifying the key, this will apply the style to all Images inside this StackPanel including NestedStackPanels -->
      <!-- Also, with BasedOn, this will inherit the style from ImageStyle defined above -->
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ImageStyle}">
         <Setter .../> <!-- In Case if you want to add another setter, for ex: Width=20. Or don't add any other Setter to have the original style-->
      </Style>
   </StackPanel.Resources>
   <StackPanel x:Name="NestedStackPanel1">
      <Image />
      <Image />
      <Image />
      <Image />
   </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel x:Name="NestedStackPanel2">
      <Image />
      <Image />
      <Image />
      <Image />
   </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

If you need to have different style for each nestedStackPanel, you can move the styling inside the nestedStackPanel, instead.

Comment: Thanks, I though the solution would be something like this.